# How do you make <h1> into a hyperlink to <h2> (for example) in html?

Tags: html, hyperlink, header

I don't do html for a living.  I don't play an html coder on TV.  I know enough to break things.

I've tried lots of things but I can't get what I want:

```
<h1>Header 1</h1>

<h2>Header 2</h2>
```

## Header 1

### Header 2

How do I make the text "Header 1" into a hyperlink to the h2 section "Header 2"?

I've searched on-line and seen the anchor and section posts, but I don't see how to make either of those link from h1 to h2.

?

Thanks for tolerating someone who is pretty new to this.

d.

Comment: You mean whenever you click Header 1 it should go to Header 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the H1 with an anchor tag that's the easiest if you do not want JS to do the work for you

You also have to give them an id so that href attribute can recognize them.

```css
h1 a {
color:#000;
text-decoration:0;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href=#header2>Hello</a></h1>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<h2 id=header2>Header 2</h2>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Do note that href accepts a selector similar to css selectors. Id must always be prefixed by '#'

Comment: Uh, and this is the best reason I don't do this for a living.  :-)  Thanks!